# Storing DateTime fields in Azure Table Storage

Tags: python, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-account

I'm trying to store an ISO formatted DateTime in my Azure Table Storage. But every time I try, it results in this String format:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcrlN.png]

This is a summary of the effective code I'm running:

```
import jsons
from azure.functions import Out

def main(parameterTableOutputJSON: Out[str]):
    row = {'ReadOn': '2021-04-28T09:35:26.123456Z'}
    parameterTableOutputJSON.set(jsons.dumps(row))
```

Of course my real code also has the PartitionKey and RowKey columns, but I can't show those here.

How can I insert the DateTime in the Azure Table Storage like this: `2021-04-28T09:35:26.123456Z` 
Instead of this: `04/28/2021 09:35:26`

The Azure Table Storage docs tell me it supports ISO formatted date times...

Comment: Please share the complete code where you're writing the entity into Table Storage.

Comment: @GauravMantri I'm writing the entity into Table Storage by calling the `set` function. The JSON String that goes into this function is the payload that gets written to Table Storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my own problem.

The `jsons.dumps` method strips the milliseconds by default. This results in a datetime that's formatted like this: `2021-04-28T09:35:26Z` 
This format is not supported as a DateTime in Azure Table Storage.

The problem is solved by writing the last line of my code like this:

```py
parameterTableOutputJSON.set(jsons.dumps(row, strip_microseconds=False))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the newest [Azure Data Tables](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/tables/azure-data-tables) library you can use the Python `datetime` object directly within your entity and submit it for creation. Here is an example snippet:

```py
from azure.data.tables import TableClient
from datetime import datetime

client = TableClient.from_connection_string(<my_conn_str>)
my_entity = {
    "PartitionKey": <my_pk>,
    "RowKey": <my_rk>,
    "ReadOn": datetime(2021, 4, 28, 9, 36, 26, 123456)
}
client.upsert_entity(my_entity)
```

[image: Here is what the entity looks like in the Storage Explorer in the portal]

Disclaimer: I work on the Azure SDK for Python team.